# Как получить файл в виде ассоциативного массива?

Tags: php, post

Отправляю POST запрос на заглушку и получаю файл в виде строки.

```
$aHTTP = array(
    'http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query($params_info)

    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($aHTTP);
$contents = file_get_contents($sURL, false, $context);
```

Получаю строку типа:

> {"test1":"00","test2":"wait","message":"Waiting."}

Каким образом можно получить файл в виде ассоциативного массива, если ключи заранее известны?

Answer (score 0):

Вы получаете классический JSON объект. Чтобы его распарсить, вам нужно вызвать функцию `json_decode()`

```
$arr = json_decode($contents, true);
if ($arr === null) // если произошла ошибка
  die(json_last_error_msg());  // выводим текст ошибки
var_dump($arr);
```